# How to query firebase to retrieve the unique ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I'm querying data from Firebase using the following code :

```
var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/Articles");

var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj);

$scope.articles = sync.$asArray();
```

which return the following data :

```
    [{
    "emailId": "ty@ty.com",
    "post": "fgh",
    "title": "hfgh"
}, {
    "emailId": "kj@hjgfh.com",
    "post": "HHHHHH",
    "title": "Hello"
}, {
    "emailId": "hkj@gmail.com",
    "post": "Big news",
    "title": "Today's news"
}]
```

Each of the returned entry under `https://example.firebaseio.com/Articles` has a unique ID which is missing from the returned result. 
How to retrieve the unique ID.

Comment: how are you adding each article? if you're using `push` then the key will be the unique ID, in which case `sync.$asArray()` probably strips those out to return an array: use `sync.$asObject()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the special `$id` property, the relative unique firebase key.

Comment: There are few of such special properties on an AngularFire object. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-objects

Comment: It's a documented and very important attribute. Not sure "hidden" is the appropriate adjective here.